# how to change background color of my two td's using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my html code ..in the below code i am having two td's with same background color.so when i click on any of the two td's the background color must be changed using jquery.is it possible to do ????

```
<table id='main_table' style='width:1002px; border: 1px solid #ccc;'>
    <thead>
      <tr class='ab'>
             <td style='width:500px; background-color:#398bb7; color:white;' onclick=\"Consituteshow('"+cityid+"');\">By Constituency</td>
              <td  style='width:500px; background-color:#398bb7; color:white;' onclick=\"Partyshow('"+cityid+"');\">By Party</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

```
$('#main_table tr.ab td').click(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#398bb7');
});
```

---

If you want to change background color of both td

```
$('#main_table tr.ab td').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().add(this).css('background-color', '#398bb7');
});
```

---

```
$('#main_table tr.ab td').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('td').css('background-color', '#398bb7');
});
```

---

Update after OP's comment

use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your elements are added dynamically so it is not present at the time DOM ready or page load.

So you have to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

**js**

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#main_table td', function () {
        $("#main_table tr td").css("background-color", "#398bb7");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#FF00FF"); //Add your color
    });
});
```

---

Better use class

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#main_table td', function () {
        $("#main_table tr td").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

**css**

```
.active {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: @user3332446 Try 
`$(function () {
    var all_td = $('#main_table td');
    $(document).on('click', all_td, function () {
        all_td.css('background-color', '#398bb7');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    });
});`

Answer (score 3):

```
$("td").click(function(){
  $(this).css("background", "green");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#main_table .ab td").css({"background-color":"#f1f1f1"});

add this inside click event

all the td of the table background will change

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#main_table tr td").click(function() {
   $("#main_table tr td").css("background-color","#398bb7");
   $(this).css("background-color","#FF00FF"); //Add your color
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/raliguzu/1/edit)

Comment: this is perfect answer but in my project it is not working but trying to implement it!!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).on("click","td",function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $("td").click(function() {
       $(this).css("background-color","#000");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td').click(function()
              {
                  $(this).css('background-color','#ff0');
              }
);
```